# KeyError in wxpython to start up GrassRaPlaT

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-3.x

class MapFrameBase(wx.Frame):
    """!Base class for map display window

```
Derived class must use statusbarManager or override
GetProperty, SetProperty and HasProperty methods.
If derived class enables and disables auto-rendering,
it should override IsAutoRendered method.
"""
def __init__(self, parent = None, id = wx.ID_ANY, title = None,
             style = wx.DEFAULT_FRAME_STYLE, toolbars = None,
             Map = None, auimgr = None, name = None, **kwargs):
    """!
    @param toolbars array of activated toolbars, e.g. ['map', 'digit']
    @param Map instance of render.Map
    @param auimgs AUI manager
    @param name frame name
    @param kwargs wx.Frame attributes
    """


    self.Map        = Map       # instance of render.Map
    self.parent     = parent

    wx.Frame.__init__(self, parent, id, title, style = style, name = name, **kwargs)

    # available cursors
    self.cursors = {
        # default: cross
        # "default" : wx.StockCursor(wx.CURSOR_DEFAULT),
        "default" : wx.StockCursor(wx.CURSOR_ARROW),
        "cross"   : wx.StockCursor(wx.CURSOR_CROSS),
        "hand"    : wx.StockCursor(wx.CURSOR_HAND),
        "pencil"  : wx.StockCursor(wx.CURSOR_PENCIL),
        "sizenwse": wx.StockCursor(wx.CURSOR_SIZENWSE)
        }

    #
    # set the size & system icon
    #
    self.SetClientSize(self.GetSize())
    self.iconsize = (16, 16)

    self.SetIcon(wx.Icon(os.path.join(globalvar.ETCICONDIR, 'grass_map.ico'), wx.BITMAP_TYPE_ICO))

    # toolbars
    self.toolbars = {}

    #
    # Fancy gui
    #
    self._mgr = wx.aui.AuiManager(self)

def _initMap(self, map):
    """!Initialize map display, set dimensions and map region
    """
    if not grass.find_program('g.region', ['--help']):
        sys.exit(_("GRASS module '%s' not found. Unable to start map "
                   "display window.") % 'g.region')

    self.width, self.height = self.GetClientSize()

    Debug.msg(2, "MapFrame._initMap():")
    map.ChangeMapSize(self.GetClientSize())
    map.region = map.GetRegion() # g.region -upgc
    # self.Map.SetRegion() # adjust region to match display window

def SetProperty(self, name, value):
    """!Sets property"""
    self.statusbarManager.SetProperty(name, value)

def GetProperty(self, name):
    """!Returns property"""
    return self.statusbarManager.GetProperty(name)

def HasProperty(self, name):
    """!Checks whether object has property"""
    return self.statusbarManager.HasProperty(name)

def GetPPM(self):
    """! Get pixel per meter

    @todo now computed every time, is it necessary?
    @todo enable user to specify ppm (and store it in UserSettings)
    """
    # TODO: need to be fixed...
    ### screen X region problem
    ### user should specify ppm
    dc = wx.ScreenDC()
    dpSizePx = wx.DisplaySize()   # display size in pixels
    dpSizeMM = wx.DisplaySizeMM() # display size in mm (system)
    dpSizeIn = (dpSizeMM[0] / 25.4, dpSizeMM[1] / 25.4) # inches
    sysPpi  = dc.GetPPI()
    comPpi = (dpSizePx[0] / dpSizeIn[0],
              dpSizePx[1] / dpSizeIn[1])

    ppi = comPpi                  # pixel per inch
    ppm = ((ppi[0] / 2.54) * 100, # pixel per meter
                (ppi[1] / 2.54) * 100)

    Debug.msg(4, "MapFrameBase.GetPPM(): size: px=%d,%d mm=%f,%f "
              "in=%f,%f ppi: sys=%d,%d com=%d,%d; ppm=%f,%f" % \
              (dpSizePx[0], dpSizePx[1], dpSizeMM[0], dpSizeMM[1],
               dpSizeIn[0], dpSizeIn[1],
               sysPpi[0], sysPpi[1], comPpi[0], comPpi[1],
               ppm[0], ppm[1]))

    return ppm

def SetMapScale(self, value, map = None):
    """! Set current map scale

    @param value scale value (n if scale is 1:n)
    @param map Map instance (if none self.Map is used)
    """
    if not map:
        map = self.Map

    region = self.Map.region
    dEW = value * (region['cols'] / self.GetPPM()[0])
    dNS = value * (region['rows'] / self.GetPPM()[1])
    region['n'] = region['center_northing'] + dNS / 2.
    region['s'] = region['center_northing'] - dNS / 2.
    region['w'] = region['center_easting']  - dEW / 2.
    region['e'] = region['center_easting']  + dEW / 2.

    # add to zoom history
    self.GetWindow().ZoomHistory(region['n'], region['s'],
                               region['e'], region['w'])

def GetMapScale(self, map = None):
    """! Get current map scale

    @param map Map instance (if none self.Map is used)
    """
    if not map:
        map = self.Map

    region = map.region
    ppm = self.GetPPM()

    heightCm = region['rows'] / ppm[1] * 100
    widthCm  = region['cols'] / ppm[0] * 100

    Debug.msg(4, "MapFrame.GetMapScale(): width_cm=%f, height_cm=%f" %
              (widthCm, heightCm))

    xscale = (region['e'] - region['w']) / (region['cols'] / ppm[0])
    yscale = (region['n'] - region['s']) / (region['rows'] / ppm[1])
    scale = (xscale + yscale) / 2.

    Debug.msg(3, "MapFrame.GetMapScale(): xscale=%f, yscale=%f -> scale=%f" % \
                  (xscale, yscale, scale))

    return scale

def GetProgressBar(self):
    """!Returns progress bar

    Progress bar can be used by other classes.
    """
    return self.statusbarManager.GetProgressBar()

def GetMap(self):
    """!Returns current Map instance
    """
    return self.Map

def GetWindow(self):
    """!Get map window"""
    return self.MapWindow

def GetMapToolbar(self):
   """!Returns toolbar with zooming tools"""
   raise NotImplementedError()

def GetToolbar(self, name):
    """!Returns toolbar if exists else None.

    Toolbars dictionary contains currently used toolbars only.
    """
    if name in self.toolbars:
        return self.toolbars[name]

    return None

def StatusbarUpdate(self):
    """!Update statusbar content"""
    self.statusbarManager.Update()

def IsAutoRendered(self):
    """!Check if auto-rendering is enabled"""
    return self.GetProperty('render')

def CoordinatesChanged(self):
    """!Shows current coordinates on statusbar.

    Used in BufferedWindow to report change of map coordinates (under mouse cursor).
    """
    self.statusbarManager.ShowItem('coordinates')

def StatusbarReposition(self):
    """!Reposition items in statusbar"""
    self.statusbarManager.Reposition()

def StatusbarEnableLongHelp(self, enable = True):
    """!Enable/disable toolbars long help"""
    for toolbar in self.toolbars.itervalues():
        toolbar.EnableLongHelp(enable)

def IsStandalone(self):
    """!Check if Map display is standalone"""
    raise NotImplementedError("IsStandalone")

def OnRender(self, event):
    """!Re-render map composition (each map layer)
    """
    raise NotImplementedError("OnRender")

def OnDraw(self, event):
    """!Re-display current map composition
    """
    self.MapWindow.UpdateMap(render = False)

def OnErase(self, event):
    """!Erase the canvas
    """
    self.MapWindow.EraseMap()

def OnZoomIn(self, event):
    """!Zoom in the map.
    Set mouse cursor, zoombox attributes, and zoom direction
    """
    toolbar = self.GetMapToolbar()
    self._switchTool(toolbar, event)

    win = self.GetWindow()
    self._prepareZoom(mapWindow = win, zoomType = 1)

def OnZoomOut(self, event):
    """!Zoom out the map.
    Set mouse cursor, zoombox attributes, and zoom direction
    """
    toolbar = self.GetMapToolbar()
    self._switchTool(toolbar, event)

    win = self.GetWindow()
    self._prepareZoom(mapWindow = win, zoomType = -1)

def _prepareZoom(self, mapWindow, zoomType):
    """!Prepares MapWindow for zoom, toggles toolbar

    @param mapWindow MapWindow to prepare
    @param zoomType 1 for zoom in, -1 for zoom out
    """
    mapWindow.mouse['use'] = "zoom"
    mapWindow.mouse['box'] = "box"
    mapWindow.zoomtype = zoomType
    mapWindow.pen = wx.Pen(colour = 'Red', width = 2, style = wx.SHORT_DASH)

    # change the cursor
    mapWindow.SetCursor(self.cursors["cross"])

def _switchTool(self, toolbar, event):
    """!Helper function to switch tools"""
    if toolbar:
        toolbar.OnTool(event)
        toolbar.action['desc'] = ''

def OnPointer(self, event):
    """!Sets mouse mode to pointer."""
    self.MapWindow.mouse['use'] = 'pointer'

def OnPan(self, event):
    """!Panning, set mouse to drag
    """
    toolbar = self.GetMapToolbar()
    self._switchTool(toolbar, event)

    win = self.GetWindow()
    self._preparePan(mapWindow = win)

def _preparePan(self, mapWindow):
    """!Prepares MapWindow for pan, toggles toolbar

    @param mapWindow MapWindow to prepare
    """
    mapWindow.mouse['use'] = "pan"
    mapWindow.mouse['box'] = "pan"
    mapWindow.zoomtype = 0

    # change the cursor
    mapWindow.SetCursor(self.cursors["hand"])

def OnZoomBack(self, event):
    """!Zoom last (previously stored position)
    """
    self.MapWindow.ZoomBack()

def OnZoomToMap(self, event):
    """!
    Set display extents to match selected raster (including NULLs)
    or vector map.
    """
    self.MapWindow.ZoomToMap(layers = self.Map.GetListOfLayers())

def OnZoomToWind(self, event):
    """!Set display geometry to match computational region
    settings (set with g.region)
    """
    self.MapWindow.ZoomToWind()

def OnZoomToDefault(self, event):
    """!Set display geometry to match default region settings
    """
    self.MapWindow.ZoomToDefault()
```

When I try to start up GrassRaPlat in command prompt, appears this as follow:

GRASS 6.4.3RC2 (AMC):~ > Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/src/grass-6.4.3RC2/dist.i686-pc-linux-gnu/etc/wxpython/lmgr/frame.py", line 196, in **init**
    self.NewDisplay(show = False)
  File "/usr/local/src/grass-6.4.3RC2/dist.i686-pc-linux-gnu/etc/wxpython/lmgr/frame.py", line 1463, in NewDisplay
    auimgr = self._auimgr, showMapDisplay = show)
  File "/usr/local/src/grass-6.4.3RC2/dist.i686-pc-linux-gnu/etc/wxpython/lmgr/layertree.py", line 156, in **init**
    Map = self.Map, auimgr = self.auimgr)
  File "/usr/local/src/grass-6.4.3RC2/dist.i686-pc-linux-gnu/etc/wxpython/mapdisp/frame.py", line 123, in **init**
    self.statusbarManager.Update()
  File "/usr/local/src/grass-6.4.3RC2/dist.i686-pc-linux-gnu/etc/wxpython/mapdisp/statusbar.py", line 217, in Update
    item.Update()
  File "/usr/local/src/grass-6.4.3RC2/dist.i686-pc-linux-gnu/etc/wxpython/mapdisp/statusbar.py", line 508, in Update
    scale = self.mapFrame.GetMapScale()
  File "/usr/local/src/grass-6.4.3RC2/dist.i686-pc-linux-gnu/etc/wxpython/gui_core/mapdisp.py", line 168, in GetMapScale
    heightCm = region['rows'] / ppm[1] * 100
KeyError: 'rows'

Can you tell me please where is my mistake?
Thank you in advance.